# Duplicate App for over 1 million leads/contacts?

Tags: duplicate-management

We're about 4 months into our Salesforce integration but we're having a ton of problems with dupes. In our previous CRM, it would monitor the company name, email address, or phone number and ask if it was associated with a different account already in the system. I'm not seeing anything like that without an app for Salesforce.

We have more than a million leads/contacts and the apps I've been seeing (for free) only deal with a limited amount of records.

I see with the Spring 15 release, there is Data.com duplicate management...but does it work outside of Data.com?

Really, what I'm looking for is something that will catch dupes in import or on lead/contact creation and is able to scrub our dataset and suggest possible dupes. If it isn't a free app, how much can we expect to spend to get this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is available for free from Spring 15 release onwards for account,contact and lead. Details can be found in below links,

https://na1.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_data_quality_duplicate_prevention.pdf

http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_sales_duplicate_management_intro.htm

Comment: I was getting thrown off because with the Data.com references. Thanks!